# Getting around pagnation in parent relationships

Tags: ee2, relationships, pagination

I confirmed with EE that as of yet there isn't support for pagnation in a parent relationships.

Was wondering if anyone else encountered this issue and what solutions you've employed to get around it?

Answer (score 2):

Check out Better Pagination by Bold Minded/Brian Litzinger.

You should be able to achieve what you need using the limit and offset parameters with that add-on.

On GitHub:
https://github.com/litzinger/better-pagination.eeaddon